# How to you express a sentence when you mean something is obvious, but not using the word obvious?

Tags: grammaire, prononciation

In Swedish, I can say

> Jag dör = Je meurs = I'm dying

But if I insert *ju* = "obvious"

> Jag dör ju = I'm obviously dying

But *ju* does not mean directly "obvious". It's just a word that tells that the previous word is serious. Just as a swear word. For example.

> Den är där = That is there.

But if I insert *ju* it becomes:

> Den är ju där = That is obviously there

**Question:**

Does French have a similar way to say *ju* as in Swedish just to express that something is obvious?

The word *ju* is pronounced as the *J* from the word "jello" and *u* is pronounced as *U* from the word *utiliser*.

Comment: It's easy to tell something is obvious in French without using the word *obvious* given the fact that word doesn't exist in French...

Comment: I just checked [*ju* pronunciation](https://svenska.se/tre/?sok=ju&pz=1#!) [jʉː] and it's neither the *J* of *jello* [dʒ] nor the *u* of *utiliser* [y]. It sounds a little like the French *yeux*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest translation keeping the conciseness of *ju* would probably be *oui*:

> *Oui, je meurs.*

> *Oui, c'est là.*

Here are other suggestions:

Formal:

> *Certainement, assurément, évidemment, bien sûr*

Common:

> *C'est clair*